# How to launch a pdf file embedded in web browser with Reading mode and JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, pdf, jakarta-ee

I need your help with the launch of PDF file from a browser with Java and a servlet.

Now I aready have finished to build the PDF, however when I show it in the browser ( with `request.getOutputStream.write(byte[])` and the MediaType: `"application/pdf"`), the document appears with a lot of toolsbars which belong to Acrobat Reader.

[image]
I tried to disapper the toolsbars with a code, which preced the called of servlet, like this: `#toolbar=0&menubar=0&statusbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=1`

It work, however it is not the solution that I am searching, because the system has old versions and it works with the Reading mode. The solution shows a bar floating, but it is no Reading mode, like this.

[image]

I must create the pdf file with the Reading mode, but I do know how to do it. I could change to the Pdf Mode with Ctrl + H, but need the browser does it auntomately.

The Reading mode has to look like this image (At the top of the document):

[image]

Comment: In general, this is AFAIK not possible - how to display the content is basically completely dependent on what browser is displaying it, how it is configured, etc. Unless you have strict control (and knowledge) what browsers are used and how are they configured (e.g. in a corporate network), there is **no way** to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, It is very strange, ¡but it works!

I have found it by mistake when I did not write the parameter value of Acrobat correctly (The documen link is the follows: [Parameters for Opening PDF Files](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf)).

I only added any parameter used by Acrobat reader (Parameter has to exist), but you must not write its value, like in this example within the jsp which calls the servlet (I used the `pagemode` parameter).

```
<FRAME SRC='PdfServlet#pagemode'......
```

I know that is stranger, however it could be userful for anyone with the same problem.

Regards.